# Headers are missing while exporting XML to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel

In my application I have an xml file.i want to export the xml into Excel file in xls format.My problem is is while exporting headers are missing.Please find the code below.

```
private string ExportTestDatatoExcel(string testDataPath)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(testDataPath, new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
            }
        }
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(testDataPath);
        fileName += ".xls" ;
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(fileName), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
            misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlApp);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        return Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is writing out the data as expected.

Just before your `for` loop you need to add another `for` loop to add the column headers in the first row of the sheet.

```
for(int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; k++)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, k + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[k].ColumnName;
}
```

then in our outter `for` loop you need to initialize `i = 1` to account for the header row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barry for the reference.It should work when the loop is as follows

```
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count-1; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; k++)
        {                        
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, k + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[k].ColumnName;   
        }
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
    }
}
```